require('node:util') need babeljs or rollup transform?
@babel/core: "^7.24.5"
rollup: "^4.18.0"
node: v20.12.1
pnpm: 8.15.3
npm: 10.5.0
OS: Darwin
server node version is v14.17
build in node20，run in node v14.17
need require('util'), get require('node:util')
▶ node -e "require('node:util')" # node 14
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:util'

try babel repl
how to understand?
babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": { "node": "14.17" },
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "corejs": "3.37"
      }
    ],
        ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
  ]
}

rollup babel plugin
try1
    babel({
      extensions: ['.js', 'ts'],
      babelHelpers: "bundled",
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),

try2
    babel({
      extensions: ['.js', 'ts'],
      babelHelpers: "bundled",
      include: ['node_modules/**/ldapjs/**/*', 'src/**'],
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),


In node v14.17, you cannot use require("node:util"), but you can use require("util") instead.
The support for node: prefix (for built-in modules) with require(...) was added in v16.0.0 and v14.18.0 (reference: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#node-imports)
